# How to map two hibernate entities using logical operators other than equals

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is it possible to map an entity using a field where its value is within two column values of the entity being mapped. For example this doesn't work but it shows what i want to do:

```
public class Player {
   
   @Column(name = "TYPE")
   private String type;

   @Column(name = "EARNED_COUNT")
   private Long earnedCount;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE", referencedColumnName = "TYPE", insertable = false,updatable=false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "earnedCount <= upperLimit",referencedColumnName = "UPPER_LIMIT")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "earnedCount >= upperLimit",referencedColumnName = "LOWER_LIMIT"))
   })
   private Capability capability;

}

public class Capability {

   @Column(name = "TYPE")
   private String type;

   @Column(name = "LOWER_LIMIT")
   private Long lowerLimit;

   @Column(name = "UPPER_LIMIT")
   private Long upperLimit;
}
```

If this particular method is not possible, is there any other way to do this as a mapping?